# using google map plugin with cordova show blank map

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps

I want to use google map plugin in my cordova app. I Create Successfully my sha1 key with following command:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Morsali.android\debug.keystore -list -v

and I create my android and IOS Key successfully. package name , sha1 ,... import correctly :

[image]

but when I build my app with following index.html page , I see a blank map with only google icon :

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
      var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

      // Initialize the map view
      map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);

      // Wait until the map is ready status.
      map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
    }, false);

    function onMapReady() {
      var button = document.getElementById("button");
      button.addEventListener("click", onBtnClicked, false);
    }

    function onBtnClicked() {
      map.showDialog();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>PhoneGap-GoogleMaps-Plugin</h3>
    <div style="width:100%;height:400px" id="map_canvas"></div>
    <button id="button">Full Screen</button>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the plugin [googlemap-plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Map)
What is wrong with following code? how can I fix it? please help me. thank you.

Comment: Hi @mina morsali, I'm facing the same issue, How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova does a lot of rendering in WebViews instead of natively in Android's View API. Your API key you generated is strictly for "Android apps". Since you are not using the Android Google Maps API, I suggest you try restricting your key to "HTTP referrers" or even testing with "None"

Comment: I select none and also Http referrers but Does not matter... map show blank unfortunately and I don;t know why... my api key is true my script is true ,... but not show and I can not debug because ripple not show plugins correctly. please help me... thank you

Comment: Are you running on an emulator or a physical device? If you are using an emulator, are you using a version of Android with Google APIs installed?